# visible part of webpage

Tags: javascript, windows, browser

I want to know if in javascript I have access to get the visible part of a page. For example I have my website opened in chrome in fullscreen. Now if I drag over it another program like windows explorer can I get some info about the region of the webpage that is not covered by the windows explorer window?

Thanks.

Comment: please elaborate, the question is unclear. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. You can tell (to some extent) whether the window is visible at all with the [page visibility API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-page-visibility-20110602/#sec-page-visibility-introduction), but that only tells you yes/no for the window as a whole. There is no way in Javascript to determine visible regions of the page.